# Using unicode character in character literal

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode

As we know something like `'═'` will give a multi-char constant warning. The alternative is either to use 0x2550 or `"\u2550"`. However, the latter requires the printing function to support the `\u` escape sequence. However I don't want to use hexadecimal everywhere. Is there a language construct that I can use that will allow me to write `'='` when I really mean `uint32_t c = 0x2550`, i.e., `'='u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **”** As we know something like '═' will give a multi-char constant warning.

No.

> **”** The alternative is either to use 0x2550 or "\u2550".

No.

> **”** However, the latter requires the printing function to support the \u escape sequence.

No.

> **”** However I don't want to use hexadecimal everywhere. Is there a language construct that I can use that will allow me to write '═' when I really mean uint32_t c = 0x2550, i.e., '═'u.

yes.

```
uint32_t c = L'═';
```

with a source encoding that supports that character.

For characters not in the Basic Multilingual Plane of Unicode it gets more involved though, because a `wchar_t` in Windows is only 16 bits, as in original Unicode.

Comment: The `L` prefix produces a literal using `wchar_t`, which is not very portable as it is different sizes on different platforms.  In C++11, you are better off using `char16_t c = u'═';` or `char32_t c = U'═';` instead if you need to store the character in a portable numeric form.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: re portability, visual c++ doesn't yet support `u` prefix. how's that for portable, do you think? ha ha :)

Comment: anyway, `wchar_t` is very portable for the restriction noted in the answer, namely BMP. e.g. that's why many of the big portable GUI frameworks translate string literals to wide strings. so both your assumptions are wrong: contrary to your assumption that `wchar_t` isn't very portable, it is, and contrary to your assumption that C++11 `u` prefix is very portable, it isn't portable at all. yet.

Answer (score 1):

The `\u` sequence is interpreted by the C++ compiler, not by a "printing function."  However, you need to use a wide string (`std::wstring`) in order to store the character.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring s(L"\u2550");

    std::wcout << s.size() << std::endl
               << std::hex << static_cast<int>(s[0]) << std::dec << std::endl
               << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output shows that there is only one character in this string.